# LaravelCollective 6 en laravel 8 no funciona

Tags: laravel-8

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="h5">Nombre:</p>
        <p class="form-control">{{$user->name}}</p>
      { !! Form::model($user, ['route' => 'users.update', $user], 'method' => 'put') !! }
        @foreach($roles as $role)
        <div>
                <label>
                    {!!Form::checkbox('role[]', $role->id, null, ['class' => 'mr-1'])}
                    {{$role->name}}
                </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        {!!Form:close()!!}
    </div>

</div>
```

tengo el siguiente error:

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' or ',' (View:/home/vagrant/code/pos/resources/views/users/edit.blade.php)

Ya instalé `laravelcollective` con `composer` pero no me funciona, alguien que tenga el mismo problema estoy implementando `spatie` y hasta aqui quedo el proyecto no entiendo porque no lo reconoce en el blade.

Comment: Amigo te falta un ```;```

Comment: Gracias amigo ya resolvi el problema mucho ojo con las llaves de apertura y cierre {{}} y tambien con la identación saludos.

Comment: Yap, no dudes hacer tu pregunta si tienes otro problema o duda